# Parallel Hillis-Steele Scan using CUDA

Tags: algorithm, c, multithreading, cuda

I'm learning CUDA (and C to some extent), and one of the algorithms that I am learning is the Hillis-Steele scan algorithm. I wrote a program that performs a simple scan with adding.

After seeding the random number generator and doing some allocation/initialization, the program fills an array with random numbers 0-9 and copies the random array to the gpu.

The program then loops with a variable that goes through each power of 2, launching a kernel with the loop variable. The kernel uses the variable as an offset, adding two locations according to the offset according to the Hillis-Steele algorithm. After the kernel exits, the input and output arrays for the kernel are switched (double buffering). The program then copies the output array back to the host, prints out the result and frees the allocated memory.

Is there a better way for the host to interact with the kernel? There seems to be quite a bit of overhead from launching the kernel in a loop. Is there a way to implement the algorithm that doesn't require the kernel? It seems that CUDA only allows synchronizing the threads in a thread block, but this program uses multiple thread blocks.

I don't really care that the random number generation is in serial; this is just educational.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

__global__ void sumScan(float* input, float* output, unsigned int offset, unsigned int max){

    unsigned int position = (gridDim.x*blockDim.x)*blockIdx.y + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;//Calculate 1D position

    if (position < max){//If in bounds
        output[position] = input[position]; //Copy input to output
        if (position >= offset){ //Add offset element if in bounds
            output[position] += input[position - offset];
        }
    } 
}



//Generic error printer
void cudaCheckError(cudaError ce){
    if (ce != cudaSuccess){
        printf(cudaGetErrorString(ce));
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));//Initialize random number generator
    const unsigned int length = 100; //How many numbers
    const unsigned int blocksz = 1024; //Size of block
    bool print = true; //Print out complete results

    //Define grid size
    //Y dimension allows very large inputs
    const unsigned int numBlocks = (length / blocksz) + 1;
    const unsigned int numBlocksx = (numBlocks > 65535) ? 65535 : numBlocks;
    const unsigned int numBlocksy = (numBlocks / 65536) + 1;
    dim3 gridSize(numBlocksx, numBlocksy);


    //Create pointers and allocate arrays
    float* d_input;
    float* d_output;

    float* h_input;
    float* h_output;

    h_input = (float*) malloc(length*sizeof(float));
    h_output = (float*) malloc(length*sizeof(float));

    cudaCheckError( cudaMalloc(&d_input, length*sizeof(float)));
    cudaCheckError(cudaMalloc(&d_output, length*sizeof(float)));

    printf("Generating random numbers.\n");

    //Fill h_input with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){ 
        h_input[i] = rand() % 10;
    }

    printf("Copying memory.\n");

    //Copy memory to device
    cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy(d_input, h_input, sizeof(float)*length, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    unsigned int offset = 1;

    printf("Performing scan.\n");

    while (offset < (length*2)){ //For all powers of 2 up to (but not including) length

        sumScan <<<gridSize, blocksz >>>(d_input, d_output, offset, length); //Perform single iteration of scan
        cudaDeviceSynchronize(); cudaCheckError(cudaGetLastError());//Make sure everything finished

        offset <<= 1;//Multiply offset by 2


        float* temp = d_input;//Swap pointers for double buffering
        d_input = d_output;
        d_output = temp;
    }

    printf("Copying results.\n");
    //Copy memory back
    cudaCheckError(cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, length*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    if (print){
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            printf("%f\t%f\n", h_input[i], h_output[i]);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Calculation complete. Final result: %f", h_output[length - 1]);
    }

    //Free allocated memory
    cudaCheckError(cudaFree(d_input));
    cudaCheckError(cudaFree(d_output));
    free(h_input);
    free(h_output);

    getchar();//Pause at end of program

}
```

Comment: What aspects of this code do you want reviewed?

Comment: @chux I'm not sure the interaction between the host and the kernel is the best. I'm a bit uneasy about launching the kernel in the for loop and its overhead.

Comment: Suggest reviewing http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  I am still unclear what you want as it is unstated.  IOWs, I'd expect a question in your post

Comment: @chux I'll add a bit more specificity to the question. Forgot that code review prefers putting the explanation above the code instead of as a code comment.

Comment: @chux I hope that the edit added the necessary detail