# Connect Four implemented via smart contract

Tags: game, solidity

I'm learning Solidity development, so I decided that Connect Four would be a fun side-project to work on.

Here's the current flow:

- A user creates a new game and sends ether to the contract, then they get a unique ID that people can join the game with. They have the option of restricting who can join the game.
- Then either

  - Someone else joins the game and sends an equal amount of ether.
  - The game creator cancels the game creation and gets their money back.
- After that, one of:

  - A player makes a move.
  - A player forfeits the game.
  - If the other player hasn't made a move in `moveTimeout` seconds (probably will be 3 days), a player can claim victory.
  - A player makes a move **and** claims victory (this is separate to save on gas when making a normal move)
- Using [PullPayment](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/payment/PullPayment.sol) from the zeppelin-solidity library, someone can withdraw any funds that the contract owes them.

I have written a [test suite](https://github.com/dmelcer9/connect-four-dapp/blob/master/test/connectfour.js) in JS using truffle.

### ConnectFour.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import "../node_modules/zeppelin-solidity/contracts/payment/PullPayment.sol";
//function asyncSend(address dest, uint256 amount) internal;
//function withdrawPayments() public;

contract ConnectFour is PullPayment {

  enum BoardPiece {NONE, RED, BLACK}

  //Encapsulates total game lead.
  struct GameState {
    uint bid; //How much each player bids
    uint lastTimePlayed; //When was the last move made?

    address playerOneRed;
    address playerTwoBlack;

    //Board is 7 columns by 6 rows
    //0 is the bottom-left corner of the board
    //1 is the second from the left on the bottom
    //6 is the bottom-right corner
    //7 is the left on the second-to-bottom row
    //41 is the top-right
    BoardPiece[42] board;

    BoardPiece whoseTurn;

    bool restricted;
    bool isStarted;
    bool gameOver;
  }

  event logGameCreated(uint gameId, bool restricted);
  event logGameStart(uint gameId);
  event logMoveMade(uint gameId, BoardPiece who, uint8 position);
  event logGameEnd(uint gameId, address winner);
  event logGameCancel(uint gameId);

  //How long someone has to move before the other player can claim victory
  uint public moveTimeout;

  //Counter so each game has a unique ID
  uint nextID;

  //The state of all the games
  mapping (uint => GameState) games;

  modifier onlyGameExists(uint gameId) {
    require(games[gameId].playerOneRed != 0);
    _;
  }

  modifier onlyWhileNotStarted(uint gameId) {
    require(!games[gameId].isStarted && !games[gameId].gameOver);
    _;
  }

  modifier onlyWhilePlaying(uint gameId) {
    require(games[gameId].isStarted && !games[gameId].gameOver);
    _;
  }

  modifier onlyPlayers(uint gameId) {
    require(msg.sender == games[gameId].playerOneRed
      || msg.sender == games[gameId].playerTwoBlack);
      _;
  }

  //Only the player whose turn it is
  modifier onlyActivePlayer(uint gameId) {
    require(msg.sender == getActivePlayer(gameId));
    _;
  }

  //Only the player whose turn it isn't
  modifier onlyInactivePlayer(uint gameId) {
    require(msg.sender == getInactivePlayer(gameId));
    _;
  }

  modifier onlyGameCreator(uint gameId) {
    require(msg.sender == games[gameId].playerOneRed);
    _;
  }

  modifier onlyAfterTimeout(uint gameId) {
    require(now > games[gameId].lastTimePlayed + moveTimeout);
    _;
  }

  function ConnectFour(uint timeout) public {
    moveTimeout = timeout;
  }

  function() public {
    revert();
  }

  //Creates a game with a unique ID. Anyone can join this game.
  function createNewGame() external payable {
    uint gameId = createUniqueId();
    createNewGameEntry(gameId);
  }

  //Creates a game where only a specified player can join.
  function createNewRestrictedGame(address playerTwo) external payable {
    require(playerTwo != msg.sender);
    uint gameId = createUniqueId();
    games[gameId].restricted = true;
    games[gameId].playerTwoBlack = playerTwo;
    createNewGameEntry(gameId);
  }

  //Join a game that another person has created.
  function joinGame(uint gameId) external payable
    onlyGameExists(gameId)
    onlyWhileNotStarted(gameId)
  {
    require(getPlayerOne(gameId) != msg.sender);
    require(msg.value == getBid(gameId));

    if (getRestricted(gameId)) {
      require(games[gameId].playerTwoBlack == msg.sender);
    } else {
      games[gameId].playerTwoBlack = msg.sender;
    }

    games[gameId].lastTimePlayed = now;
    games[gameId].isStarted = true;
    games[gameId].whoseTurn = BoardPiece.RED;
    logGameStart(gameId);
  }

  //If nobody has joined your game, you can cancel and get money back
  function cancelCreatedGame(uint gameId)
    external
    onlyGameExists(gameId)
    onlyWhileNotStarted(gameId)
    onlyGameCreator(gameId)
  {
    games[gameId].isStarted = true;
    games[gameId].gameOver = true;

    asyncSend(msg.sender, games[gameId].bid);

    logGameCancel(gameId);
  }

  function forfeit(uint gameId)
    external
    onlyWhilePlaying(gameId)
    onlyPlayers(gameId)
  {
    if (msg.sender == games[gameId].playerOneRed) {
      gameEnd(gameId, games[gameId].playerTwoBlack);
    } else if (msg.sender == games[gameId].playerTwoBlack) {
      gameEnd(gameId, games[gameId].playerOneRed);
    } else {
      //This should never happen
      revert();
    }
  }

  function claimTimeoutVictory(uint gameId)
    external
    onlyAfterTimeout(gameId)
    onlyInactivePlayer(gameId)
    onlyWhilePlaying(gameId)
  {
    gameEnd(gameId, getInactivePlayer(gameId));
  }

  //The pieces in toClaim must be sorted positions, least to greatest
  function makeMoveAndClaimVictory(uint gameId, uint8 moveToMake, uint8[4] claim)
    external
    onlyActivePlayer(gameId)
    onlyWhilePlaying(gameId)
  {
    BoardPiece player = games[gameId].whoseTurn;
    address playerAddress = getActivePlayer(gameId);

    makeMove(gameId, moveToMake);

    require(checkHasWon(gameId, player, claim));

    gameEnd(gameId,playerAddress);
  }

  //If the move is valid, make a move on the board
  function makeMove(uint gameId, uint8 position)
    public
    onlyActivePlayer(gameId)
    onlyWhilePlaying(gameId)
  {
    BoardPiece player = games[gameId].whoseTurn;

    require(position >= 0 && position <= 41);
    require(games[gameId].board[position] == BoardPiece.NONE);

    if (position >= 7){
      require(games[gameId].board[position - 7] != BoardPiece.NONE);
    }

    games[gameId].board[position] = player;

    if (player == BoardPiece.RED) {
      games[gameId].whoseTurn = BoardPiece.BLACK;
    } else {
      games[gameId].whoseTurn = BoardPiece.RED;
    }

    logMoveMade(gameId, player, position);
  }

  //Is a set of four pieces a valid victory
  function checkHasWon(uint gameId, BoardPiece who, uint8[4] moves) constant public returns(bool){
    for (uint8 i = 0; i<4; i++){
      require(moves[i] >= 0 && moves[i] <= 41);
      require(games[gameId].board[moves[i]] == who);
    }

    //First 2 pieces must be in increasing order
    require(moves[0] < moves[1]);
    uint8 diff = moves[1] - moves[0];

    //All other pieces must line up the same as the first 2 (and also be increasing)
    require(moves[2] - moves[1] == diff &&
            moves[3] - moves[2] == diff);

    //Make sure pieces are in a valid arrangement
    //And prevent wrap-around
    if (diff == 1 || diff == 8){
      //The last piace should be further to the right than the first one
      require(moves[0] % 7 < moves[3] % 7);
    } else if (diff == 6){
      //The last piece should be further to the left than the first one
      require(moves[3] % 7 < moves[0] % 7);
    } else if (diff == 7){
      //Wrap-around isn't a problem with vertical pieces
    } else{
      revert();
    }

    return true;

  }

  //Accessor functions per game
  function getBid(uint gameId) constant public returns(uint) {
    return games[gameId].bid;
  }

  function getLastTimePlayed(uint gameId) constant public returns(uint){
    return games[gameId].lastTimePlayed;
  }

  function getPlayerOne(uint gameId) constant public returns(address){
    return games[gameId].playerOneRed;
  }

  function getPlayerTwo(uint gameId) constant public returns(address){
    return games[gameId].playerTwoBlack;
  }

  function getBoard(uint gameId) constant public returns(BoardPiece[42]){
    return games[gameId].board;
  }

  function getWhoseTurn(uint gameId) constant public returns(BoardPiece){
    return games[gameId].whoseTurn;
  }

  function getRestricted(uint gameId) constant public returns(bool){
    return games[gameId].restricted;
  }

  function getIsStarted(uint gameId) constant public returns(bool){
    return games[gameId].isStarted;
  }

  function getGameOver(uint gameId) constant public returns(bool){
    return games[gameId].gameOver;
  }

  //Player that is currently going
  function getActivePlayer(uint gameId) constant internal returns(address){
    BoardPiece player = games[gameId].whoseTurn;

    if (player == BoardPiece.RED) {
      return games[gameId].playerOneRed;
    } else if (player == BoardPiece.BLACK) {
      return games[gameId].playerTwoBlack;
    } else {
      revert();
    }
  }

  //Player that is currently not going
  function getInactivePlayer(uint gameId) constant internal returns(address){
    BoardPiece player = games[gameId].whoseTurn;

    if (player == BoardPiece.RED) {
      return games[gameId].playerTwoBlack;
    } else if (player == BoardPiece.BLACK) {
      return games[gameId].playerOneRed;
    } else {
      revert();
    }
  }

  //Increment the game ID and return it
  function createUniqueId() private returns(uint) {
    return nextID++;
  }

  //Helper function for game creation
  function createNewGameEntry(uint gameId) private{
    games[gameId].bid = msg.value;
    games[gameId].playerOneRed = msg.sender;
    logGameCreated(gameId, false);
  }

  //Helper function for game end
  function gameEnd(uint gameId, address winner) private {
    games[gameId].gameOver = true;
    uint256 payout = games[gameId].bid * 2;

    asyncSend(winner, payout);

    logGameEnd(gameId, winner);
  }

}
```

Comment: A Connect Four which starts like `contract ConnectFour is PullPayment`, interesting.

Comment: @Mast That's more of a syntax thing. Solidity uses `is` instead of `extends` and the best (only?) way to use [PullPayment](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/payment/PullPayment.sol) is inheritance. There are other ways to use some kinds of libraries, but this works well. (Solidity has multiple inheritance so this doesn't restrict other functionality)

Comment: Oh, I don't doubt it. We don't have any questions yet in that language so it may take a while before you have an answer, but I see you [have experience](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134328/52915) with questions staying unanswered. That's sad really, I wish you a great answer.

Comment: @Mast Thanks! Luckily none of these are too important. Once I finish a frontend I'll probably launch this on the testnet, so no real money could be lost